TCP Provider: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
I have a Python web application that is failing to connect to a local SQL server express installation through SQLAlchemy. I can connect to the database via SSMS using SQL server auth login. I have confirmed  firewall port rules for port 1433 are fine and I have confirmed ODBC drivers are installed on Windows.
When connecting to MS SQL server via SQLAlchemy I am using the URI string:
@URI=mssql+pyodbc://dbuser:dbpasswd@host\SQLEXPRESS:1433/mydb;Trusted_Connection=yes;?driver=SQL Server Native Client 11.0
Does anyone see an issue with the above URI string format or have you come across this issue and fixed it another way?
Tried modifying the format of the URI with no success in getting connection.
*Can see an exception in Python stack trace where SQLAlchemy bind connection call results in no connection exception. *
Have installed pyodbc 5.1.0
Tried refreshing the DSN and driver list for ODBC connectivity.
Tried reviewing firewall rules for connectivity blocks

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

When connected via SSMS does SELECT * FROM [sys].[dm_tcp_listener_states] return any rows?

Hi Gord, I see only two entries as follows 1 :: 0 62758 0 TSQL 0 ONLINE
2 0.0.0.0 1 62758 0 TSQL 0 ONLINE

So the instance is listening on port 62758, not port 1433.
